# How to share data between Ruby and Bash through the YAML?

Tags: ruby, bash, yaml

First of all, I have a need to use the same information between Ruby and Bash scripts.

I never did that, either never used YAML. Why do I think of YAML, is that Ruby has rather good support of it from the standard library. The problem is that I can't find any information about Bash and YAML interaction. I want to write some YAML file (say, foo.yml) and use its contents in both scripts: bar.rb and baz.sh.

Maybe YAML usage is wrong there? What is the most correct approach to share data between programs?

Comment: What kind of data? Using Yaml from Bash sounds like not at all fun, but if your structures are reasonably simple, maybe it could be feasible.

Comment: The Ruby program is a command line tool. The Bash script is a file, stored in /etc/bash_completion.d/foo. I want to use YAML for command line options storage of Ruby program. Why do I need this? I think YAML would be convenient way to share command line options between both programs (The DRY principle or whatever). So, basically, Bash script is a script for autocompletion. I don't want to write the same options twice (in both programs) and foo.yml should help me there.

Comment: Why not just generate the autocompletion configuration based on your YAML file? The options won't be changing all the time so why bother trying to make the autocompletion configuration dynamic?

Comment: Why? I don't know :) What do you mean by "generate"? Currently I have neither foo.yml, nor baz.sh file. I just wonder what is the right way.

Comment: Create an option for your Ruby script to output a Bash auto-completion script from its internal database instead.

Comment: So, basically, you are implying about writing Bash code inside Ruby file? Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

YAML has support for complex data structures which are not supported by bash. The first example that comes in mind is Associative Arrays.

I would suggest generating appropriate data structures from Ruby and source them in bash.

```
. <(/path/to/your/ruby/script --generate-completion-data)
```

The output of the ruby script when called with --generate-completion-data should be a valid bash script, defining the variables you will use in your completion script/procedure

For example:

```
CMD_OPTS=(--help --print --version)
CMD_F_OPTS=(--audio --video)
```

And your completion script may look like:

```
. <(/path/to/your/ruby/script --generate-completion-data)

__is_file_opt {
    for element in ${CMD_F_OPTS[*]};
        if [[ $1 == $element ]]; then 
            return 0;
        fi
    done
    return 1;
}
__ruby_script_complete {
    local cur prev
    COMPREPLY=()

    #_get_cword  is a function defined by /etc/bash_completion in Ubuntu, returns 
    # the current word to complete may not be available in your version
    cur=`_get_cword` 

    prev=${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD-1]}

    if [[ "$cur" == -* ]]; then
        COMPREPLY=($( compgen -W "${CMD_OPTS[*]} ${CMD_F_OPTS[*]}" -- "$cur" ))               
        return 0;
    fi

    if __is_file_opt $prev; then
        COMPREPLY=( $( compgen -f -- $cur ) \
                    $( compgen -d -- $cur ) )
    fi
    return 0

}
```

Note: the above script isn't tested, it's just an example

Comment: Well, thanks, but I ended up with Regexp parsing of 'help' command of command line Ruby utility. Why? Because everyone do that, so it seems to be natural. And YAML… Probably, it was an overkill desicion.